# Is there any way to disable the repeated animation in the notification bar, for app update downloads?

Tags: notification-bar, 9.0-pie, accessibility

I've just acquired an Android 9 phone.  It is part of the Android One scheme, so the software should be really stock Android.  I do not currently wish to install a custom ROM, or otherwise mod the OS at a root level.

I've turned it on, and obviously it started catching up with updates :-).

I don't like that it keeps showing an animated download icon at the top of the screen.  I don't want my attention repeatedly drawn to this, thanks.  (I don't know why anyone would?)

I have set "Remove animations" in the accessibility settings.  However, the animation still keeps appearing.

Is there a way to disable this animation?

Presumably I could go in "Manage Notifications" and disable Google Play Store, but...

I happened to notice that in "Manage Notifications", if I click on "Google Play Store" (instead of the toggle button next to it), I get a detailed list of notifications which I can disable individually.  Some of these look important.  I don't want to disable notifications that critical security updates have been released for Chrome, Play Services, and so on!

I can see seven "categories" of notifications.  Does one of these cover the animated download icon?  If so, what else will it disable?

1. High priority
2. Account alerts
3. App updates available
4. Updated apps
5. Security and maintenance
6. Connectivity
7. Device setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have Android 9, but if some of the notifications are like on Android 8, then you can try the following:

1. Open Settings -> Apps & Notifications. Click on "See all apps", then the 3-dot and select Show system apps.
2. Look for Download Manager, click on it.
3. Click "App Notifications" or "Notifications", then disable "In progress"

**Note:** You may find 2 Download Manager. One of them will have the notifications' categories listed.

Comment: Settings -> Apps -> All apps shows Google Play Services and `com.google.android.apps.handwriting.ime`, but it does not show Download Manager. Google Play Services has a category for "System update", which at least provides some reassurance, but nothing else relevant.

Comment: "Manage notifications" is equivalent to Settings -> Apps & Notifications -> Notifications -> See all from last 7 days. This shows a list of apps sorted by most recent notification. It includes Google Play Services. When the download icon was animating, I think the "notifications drawer" showed a notification from the specific app - Play Services for system updates, Play Store for app updates, and the same for the Map app when downloading offline maps.

Comment: @sourcejedi I find it strange that there is  no Download Manager listed among your apps even when you select to show system apps. Are you able to view the list of all apps installed on your phone?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't followed your instructions correctly.

Comment: @sourcejedi The same notification is also present on Android 9. Did stop also stop the animated download icon?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer!